# 'transferUtility' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to Amazon AWS in my C# application using transferUtility as follows:

```
client.transferUtility.BeginUpload(request, callback, null);
```

And I get the error:

```
 The name 'transferUtility' does not exist in the current context
```

I imported Amazon.S3.Model.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `using Amazon.S3.Transfer;`

[Class TransferUtility](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility.htm)